# How to declare commands local to a plugin?

Tags: command-line, plugin-system

Writing a vim plugin, I can use

```
function! s:InternalMethod()
endfunction
```

for `InternalMethod` to be local to the plugin environment. It will not be directly available to users nor overwrite their methods.

How do I perform a similar encapsulation on internal commands?

```
command! -nargs=1 InternalCommand <q-args>
```

Does this even make sense?

Comment: Well, does it? :) I think you can ask the same thing about mappings then.

Comment: @VanLaser Yeah, I guess you're right. I finally came out with another `InternalMethod`.. which finally seems like a pretty sane approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim's help about defining a new command (`:com[mand][!] [{attr}...] {cmd} {rep}` at `:h E174`) states:

> Define a ***user*** command.  The name of the command is
>       {cmd} and its replacement text is {rep}.  The command's
>       attributes (see below) are {attr}.  If the command
>       already exists, an error is reported, unless a ! is
>       specified, in which case the command is redefined.

Note the *user* attribute - in my understanding, commands (and mappings) are created for the user; this means that indeed it won't make much sense to have commands "not directly available to users".

In other words, since one can always call a function from a script, commands and mappings are user commodities :)

Comment: Which makes perfect sense indeed ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it makes sense. I have a few plugins that define command not exported to the end user. Sometimes, we, plugin writers, are the user. And commands can help us provide more advanced stuff.

The way I do it: I define the commands I need in the function scope where I use them, and finally (in a finally clause), I delete the commands I've defined for my own selfish needs.

Comment: Well, why not? :) But how do you actually define them "in the function scope where you use them"? i.e. is there any actual difference in how the command is defined? (similar to `s:function()` for functions).

Comment: I suppose, if you source the file manually, you get all those commands defined, but if the user loads the plugin, the commands get deleted automatically - that's nice :) (upvoted)

Comment: Everything is as usual. I just don't forget to call `delcommand` when I'm done. Check for instance the `s:help()` function [over there](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template/blob/master/after/plugin/mu-template.vim#L675)